# Conways game of life trying to get the code behind working

Tags: c#, wpf, conways-game-of-life

i have four classes

```
    public class BoolToCol : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool v = (bool)value;
            if (v == true)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }



    public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public bool _ItsAlive;
        public int _CellIndex;
        public bool ItsAlive { 
            get {return _ItsAlive;} 
            set{
                _ItsAlive = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItsAlive"));
                }
            } 
        }
        public int CellIndex
        {
            get { return _CellIndex; }
            set
            {
                _CellIndex = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CellIndex"));
                }
            }
        }
    }



<Window x:Class="Pucketts_ConWaysGameOfLife.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Game of Life" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="58*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Black"
              Grid.Column="0">

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="80"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height"
                            Value="20"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                            Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                            Value="Top"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                            Value="3"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Slider">
                    <Setter Property="TickFrequency"
                            Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="SmallChange"
                            Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSnapToTickEnabled"
                            Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="LargeChange"
                            Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="Minimum"
                            Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="80"/>
                </Style>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foregroundBrush"
                                 Color="Red"/>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="68"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="76"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="68"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Content="GenSlide"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Content="Width"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Content="Height"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    LargeChange="2"
                    x:Name="GenSlide"
                    Maximum="15"/>
            <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="WidthSlide"
                    Maximum="100"/>
            <Slider Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    x:Name="HeightSlide"
                    Maximum="100"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2"
                    Click="SetGrid"
                    Content="Set Grid"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="0"
                    Click="Random"
                    Content="Random"/>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   x:Name="GenNum"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=GenSlide, Path= Value}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   x:Name="WidthNum"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=WidthSlide, Path= Value}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   x:Name="HeightNum"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=HeightSlide, Path= Value}"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Click="Play"
                    Content="Play"/>

            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Click="Next"
                    Margin="0,0,0,-10"
                    Content="Next"/>
        </Grid>
        <UniformGrid  x:Name="Board" 
          Grid.Column="1">

        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>



    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Cell[] CellA;
        int _NumOfColumns;
        int CellIndex;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }
        public int NumOfColumns
        {
            get { return _NumOfColumns; }
            set
            {
                _NumOfColumns = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NumOfColumns"));
                }
            }
        }
        private void Initializeboard()
        {
            NumOfColumns = (int) (this.HeightSlide.Value);
            CellA = new Cell[NumOfColumns * (int) (this.WidthSlide.Value)];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.HeightSlide.Value * this.WidthSlide.Value; i++)
            {
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
                rec.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
                rec.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(rec_MouseLeftButtonDown);
                this.Board.Children.Add(rec);
                Cell c = new Cell();
                c.CellIndex = i;
                Binding newB = new Binding("ItsAlive");
                newB.Source = c;
                newB.Converter = new BoolToCol();
                rec.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, newB);
                CellA[i] = c;
            }

        }

        public void rec_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (UIElement item in this.Board.Children)
            {
                if (item.IsMouseOver)
                {
                    Cell c = (item as Rectangle).GetBindingExpression(Rectangle.FillProperty).ResolvedSource as Cell;
                    c.ItsAlive = !c.ItsAlive;
                    //c.CellIndex = this.Board.Children.IndexOf((Rectangle) sender);
                    CellIndex = c.CellIndex;
                    Console.WriteLine(CellIndex + " " + CellA[CellIndex].ItsAlive);
                }
            }
        }
        public List<Cell> CheckNeighbours(Cell c)
        {
            //NumOfColumns

            //c.CellIndex
            // 3 secations the ones above below and next to
            List<Cell> NebourCell = new List<Cell> { };
            NebourCell.Clear();
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    NebourCell.Add(CellA[c.CellIndex - NumOfColumns - i]);


                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Ignore");
                }
            }
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i += 2)
            {
                try
                {
                    NebourCell.Add(CellA[c.CellIndex -i]);

                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Ignore for middle index out of bounds");
                }
            }
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    NebourCell.Add(CellA[c.CellIndex + NumOfColumns - i]);

                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Ignore");
                }

            }
            return NebourCell;



        }
        private void SetGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Board.Children.Clear();
            this.Initializeboard();
        }

        private void Random(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            foreach (UIElement item in this.Board.Children)
            {
                Cell c = (item as Rectangle).GetBindingExpression(Rectangle.FillProperty).ResolvedSource as Cell;
                if (rand.Next(0, 2) == 1)
                {
                    c.ItsAlive = !c.ItsAlive;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Play(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UIElement item in this.Board.Children)
            {


            }
        }

        private void Next(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int Alive = 0;

            foreach (Cell AllCell in CellA)
            {
                List<Cell> NebourCells = CheckNeighbours(CellA[AllCell.CellIndex]);
                foreach ( Cell AllBebourCells in NebourCells)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(CellA[AllBebourCells.CellIndex].ItsAlive);
                    if (CellA[AllBebourCells.CellIndex].ItsAlive)
                        Alive++;   
                }


                Console.WriteLine(Alive);

                if (Alive < 2 || Alive > 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It dies");
                    CellA[CellIndex].ItsAlive = false;
                }
                if (Alive == 2 || Alive == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Its lives on");
                }
                if (Alive == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Its alive");
                    CellA[CellIndex].ItsAlive = true;
                }
                //foreach (Cell item in NebourCell)
                //{
                //    Rectangle ind = this.Board.Children[item.CellIndex] as Rectangle;
                //    ind.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCyan);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem i believe is in the Main Window cs and when you put three squares in a row and you go to next gen it is suppose to go vertical but mine just deletes the farthest one to the right i have been working on this for a while now i have been doing a lot of Debugging i have also debugged with break points i think it also is in the Next Button event Method but i could not find the problem and was wondering if anyone could assist me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your `Next` method that I can see.  First, you are not resetting your 'Alive' value between each cell that you process.  So if the first cell you process has two alive neighbors, you `Alive` variable gets set to 2, and then if the next cell also has two alive neighbors, `Alive` is now set to 4!

Secondly, you are currently modifying the cells in place.  This will lead to incorrect results, as if a certain cell dies, it will no longer be counted as alive for the processing of the cells next to it when it should be.  You will need to create a temporary cell array that is a copy of `CellA`, and use the alive status of the cell in `CellA` but modify the status in the copy.  Then at the end, set `CellA` to the copy.

Your new function should flow like this, in pseudocode

```
private void Next(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Cell[] copy = copy of CellA
   Loop over cells in copy
   {
       Alive = number of living neighbors of cell in CellA array
       // apply Life logic here
       copy[cell index].IsAlive = new status based on logic
   }
   CellA = copy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you evolve your population (your CellA variable), you have to work on a copy of it. That is, you generate the new generation of cells into a newly allocated variable that you then assign to CellA only when you are done.